# Please suggest a good IDE for developing facebook applications

Tags: facebook

I am hosting my application on a web hosting service www.110mb.com. Can you please suggest a good IDE and also the additional plugins (FTP,PHP etc) I would need to install in order to run my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Eclipse + PDT**](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)

If you need FTP support use [**Eclipse-SFTP**](http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-sftp/).

Of course - some people would just resort to [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is pretty sweet for PHP, Java, and Python (Pydev).

Subclipse is an excellent plugin if you use SVN.